# Assembly Language: How do I print the value of ax command line?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

Assembly language. I am using masm32.
Let's say I have ax = 100h.
How do I print the value of ax on command line. 
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709042/simple-way-to-print-value-of-a-register-in-x86-assembly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple way to print value of a register in x86 assembly.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709042/simple-way-to-print-value-of-a-register-in-x86-assembly)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [official MASM32](http://masm32.com/) package then it has a bunch of console related stuff already included, all you have to do is reference masm32.lib and call the appropriate function. The info for all this is included in the package and you will already have a local copy, you just have to read the right .chm file.

This [MASM32 forum post](http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?topic=12515.0) may help point you in the right direction.